# How can I get a substring of a string in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I have a string like "Test.m", how can I get just the substring "Test" from that via elisp? I'm trying to use this in my `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One way is to use `substring` (or `substring-no-properties`):

```
(substring "Test.m" 0 -2) => "Test"
```

> (`substring` *STRING*  *FROM* `&optional` *TO* )
>
> Return a new string whose contents are a substring of *STRING*. The
>   returned string consists of the characters between index *FROM*
>   (inclusive) and index *TO* (exclusive) of *STRING*.  *FROM* and *TO* are
>   zero-indexed: 0 means the first character of *STRING*.  **Negative values
>   are counted from the end of *STRING*.**  If *TO* is `nil`, the substring runs
>   to the end of *STRING*.

Answer (score 11):

[Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12284574/596361) is idiomatic, when you just need a filename without extension. However, if you manipulate files and filepaths heavily in your code, i recommend installing Johan Andersson's [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) file and directory API, because it provides many functions absent in Emacs with a consistent API. Check out functions [`f-base`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-base-path) and [`f-no-ext`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-no-ext-path):

```
(f-base "~/doc/index.org") ; => "index"
(f-no-ext "~/doc/index.org") ; => "~/doc/index"
```

If, instead, you work with strings often, install Magnar Sveen's [`s.el`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) for the same reasons. You might be interested in [`s-chop-suffix`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-chop-suffix-suffix-s):

```
(s-chop-suffix ".org" "~/doc/index.org") ; => "~/doc/index"
```

For generic substring retrieval use [dkim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12274641/596361).

Comment: Just for basic substrings from directories and file names, there are the `File Name Components` functions in elisp https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html

Answer (score 10):

In your particular case, you might like to use `file-name-sans-extension`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most flexible option (although it's not clear if you need flexibility) would be to use `replace-regexp-in-string`:

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `replace-regexp-in-string` <kbd>RET</kbd>

e.g.:

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\..*" "" "Test.m")
```